# Find matching interval in SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table:

table:

```
start         end
1 Jan 09    31 Jan 2009
1 Feb 09    28 Feb 2009
1 Mar 09    31 Mar 2009
1 Apr 09    01 May 2009
1 May 09    31 May 2009
1 Jun 09    01 Jul 2009
1 Jul 09    31 Jul 2009
1 Aug 09    31 Aug 2009
1 Sep 09    01 Oct 2009
1 Oct 09    31 Oct 2009
1 Nov 09    01 Dec 2009
1 Dec 09    31 Dec 2009
1 Jan 10    31 Jan 2010
1 Feb 10    03 Mar 2010
1 Mar 10    31 Mar 2010
1 Apr 10    01 May 2010
1 May 10    31 May 2010
1 Jun 10    01 Jul 2010
1 Jul 10    31 Jul 2010
1 Aug 10    31 Aug 2010
1 Sep 10    01 Oct 2010
1 Oct 10    31 Oct 2010
1 Nov 10    01 Dec 2010
1 Dec 10    31 Dec 2010
1 Jan 09    31 Mar 2009
1 Apr 09    30 Jun 2009
1 Jul 09    01 Oct 2009
1 Oct 09    31 Dec 2009
1 Jan 10    31 Mar 2010
1 Apr 10    30 Jun 2010
1 Jul 10    01 Oct 2010
1 Oct 10    31 Dec 2010
1 Jan 09    31 Dec 2009
1 Jan 10    31 Dec 2010
```

The above contains for each month, quarter and year of 2009, 2010.

I have another table with the following:

table2

```
start       end
15-12-09    31-12-09
15-01-12    31-12-13
01-01-11    31-12-13
30-01-98    31-12-13
01-01-98    31-12-13
01-01-98    31-12-13
23-12-12    31-12-13
12-11-11    31-12-13
01-01-10    31-12-13
```

For each entry in table2, I need to find the possible timeframes it falls into table1.

For ex. from table2, first entry -

```
15-12-09    31-12-09
```

falls to:

```
1 Dec 09    31 Dec 2009
1 Oct 09    31 Dec 2009
1 Jan 09    31 Dec 2009
```

Is it possible in Oracle SQL to identify it?

Comment: If possible can u provide insert script?

Comment: Return the records where the end date in one table is after or equal to the start date in the other table AND the start date in the table is before or equal to the end date of the other table.

Comment: Marmite Bomber's answer provides correct answers for both scenarios...

Answer (score 3):

You must first define what do you mean with *falls in table1* interval

There are general two possible interpretation. A more restrictive is the **SUBINTERVAL**,
i.e. the matched interval is completely covered with the reference interval.

```
 match              <----------> 
 reference    <------------------>
```

Other more relaxed possibility is **INTERSECT** that means there is at least one point common to the both intervals.

```
 match                       <----------> 
 reference   <------------------>
```

Dependent on that decision you use a different join condition.
In the query below the first possibility is implemented, simple swap the comments to  get the other option.

Note that tables with your simulated data are created below.

```
select 
   tab2.start_d match_start, tab2.end_d match_end, 
   tab.start_d ref_start, tab.end_d ref_end 
from tab2 
join tab
-- option SUBINTERVAL
on tab.start_d <= tab2.start_d and tab2.end_d <= tab.end_d
-- option INTERSEC
--  on NOT (tab2.end_d <  tab.start_d OR tab2.start_d > tab.end_d)
order by 1,2,3;
```

result for the SUBINTERVAL option

```
MATCH_START       MATCH_END         REF_START         REF_END         
----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------
15.12.09 00:00:00 31.12.09 00:00:00 01.01.09 00:00:00 31.12.09 00:00:00 
15.12.09 00:00:00 31.12.09 00:00:00 01.10.09 00:00:00 31.12.09 00:00:00 
15.12.09 00:00:00 31.12.09 00:00:00 01.12.09 00:00:00 31.12.09 00:00:00
```

You'll get far more records for the INTERSECT option.

And here the test data

```
create table tab as
with tab as (
-- reference intervals
-- months
select add_months(to_date('01012009','ddmmyyyy'),rownum-1) start_d,
add_months(to_date('01012009','ddmmyyyy'),rownum)-1 end_d from dual connect by level <=24
union all
-- quartals
select add_months(to_date('01012009','ddmmyyyy'),3*(rownum-1)) start_d,
add_months(to_date('01012009','ddmmyyyy'),3*rownum)-1 end_d from dual connect by level <=24/3
union all
-- years
select add_months(to_date('01012009','ddmmyyyy'),12*(rownum-1)) start_d,
add_months(to_date('01012009','ddmmyyyy'),12*rownum)-1 end_d from dual connect by level <=24/12
) 
select * from tab;

create table tab2 as
with tab2 as (
-- matched intervals
select to_date('15-12-09','dd-mm-rr') start_d,     to_date('31-12-09','dd-mm-rr') end_d from dual union all
select to_date('15-01-12','dd-mm-rr') start_d,     to_date('31-12-13','dd-mm-rr') end_d from dual union all
select to_date('15-01-98','dd-mm-rr') start_d,     to_date('31-12-13','dd-mm-rr') end_d from dual
)
select * from tab2;
```

Comment: it fails if I change 15-01-12 to 15-01-98 in tab2.

Comment: @dang what fails? The interval 15-01-98 to 31-12-13  is not included in any interval of `tab`, there for the query returns NULLs in the START and END columns. I added this new line to `tab2`

Comment: If I change select to_date('15-01-12','dd-mm-rr') start_d,     to_date('31-12-13','dd-mm-rr') end_d from dual TO select to_date('15-01-98','dd-mm-rr') start_d,     to_date('31-12-13','dd-mm-rr') end_d from dual, it gives me NULL

Comment: @dang - what other value do you expect to get? *For each entry in table2, I need to find the possible timeframes it falls into table1* Do you mean **that intersect** with table1? I.e. in this case all records from table1?

Comment: what is the final query?

Answer (score 2):

Simple between should help.

Use two between statements first to check whether start_date of table2 inside the timeframe of table1, second between will check whether end_date of table2 also inside that same timeframe of table1. Both checks should hold at the same time, so you should use and between them.

Also, being an inclusive "between" works following way: for the first parameter 
it checks `>` or `=` and for the second parameter `<` or `=`.

So the following statements are equals:

```
t2.start_date between t1.start_date and t1.end_date
```

and

```
t2.start_date >= t1.start_date and t2.start_date <= t1.end_date
```

The SQL you are looking for will be following:

```
select t2.*, '->', t1.* from table2 t2,
  table1 t1
  where t2.start_date between t1.start_date and t1.end_date
    and t2.end_date between t1.start_date and t1.end_date
```

Answer (score 1):

First, life will be so much simpler if you store everything in standard DATE format so that you are not converting in the queries.  Then pattern is simply:

```
WHERE table2.start <= table1.end
  AND table1.start <= table2.end
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, best way to express intersection of intervals I found is:

```
select *
from table2 
join table1 
on
   table1.start between table2.start and table2.end
   or 
   table2.start between table1.start and table1.end;
```

Every case of intersection falls in one of these two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I chose not very simple way without great performance =)

```
with days (dt, max_dt) as
  (select (select min(start_dt) from table2) as dt
         ,(select max(end_dt) from table2) as max_dt
   from dual
   union all
   select dt+1 as dt
         ,max_dt as max_dt
   from days
   where dt <max_dt
  )
select distinct
       t2.start_dt as start_dt2
      ,t2.end_dt as end_dt2
      ,t.start_dt as start_dt
      ,t.end_dt as end_dt
from table2 t2
join days d on (t2.start_dt <=d.dt and t2.end_dt >= d.dt)
join table t on (t.start_dt <=d.dt and t.end_dt >= d.dt)
```

I try to cover cases below:

```
table interval        |---------|
table2 interval    |---------------|
table2 interval         |----|
table2 interval             |--------|
table2 interval    |-----|
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know what you mean and what you wanted to achieve here but I hope this would be of help to you. Somehow, I was able to get the output you were referring (partly). Just do a little tweak on this code.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CONVERT(DATE,tbl1.START)) 'start',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CONVERT(DATE,tbl1.[END])) 'end',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CONVERT(DATE,tbl2.START)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CONVERT(DATE,tbl2.[END])) 'table2'
```

FROM    tbl1, tbl2
where   (CONVERT(DATE,tbl2.START) >= CONVERT(DATE,tbl1.START)) AND
        (CONVERT(DATE,tbl2.[END]) <= CONVERT(DATE,tbl1.[END]))

Comment: Hmmm. This doesn't seem like Oracle syntax. What do you think [CONVERT() function does](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions041.htm#SQLRF00620)?